# What would Detect Evil show on a villain who is self righteous and truly believes they are in the right

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, alignment

A good example of this would be Thanos. His goal was to murder half of sentient life in the universe but he honest to god believed he was doing it to solve the problem of limited resources.

Comment: Voting to close as "opinion based", but for the benefit of newer members of the stack I offer further explanation:  Questions dealing with alignment systems, especially as they mesh with mechanics, often devolve into opinion-based answers even if the rules seem to be tightly written.  In this case, you're question really becomes "Is Thanos Evil?" which is very much an opinion question, and we don't pursue those questions here.

Comment: Alignment questions of this sort are [off-topic here as they are _always_ purely opinion-based](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5357/4563). Alignment is described as objective—and in-character, it is—but there aren’t actually objective rules for deciding alignment. It’s all just left to the GM’s opinion. There is no way anyone can answer this for anyone else.

Comment: Your example is wrong: Killing half of the universe was the *means* for his goal.

Comment: @Novak the question is not opinion based. I would argue it is a valid question that many players and DM's face. A player could easily argue with a DM that their actions are self righteous and thus they don't consider themselves evil, however a DM reserves the right to tell the players that no, their actions would in fact put them into a position where their alignment could be compromised . Thanos is a good example because he is seen as the "bad" guy in the movies for very obvious reasons. He knew what he was doing was wrong, but he felt he had to do it anyway.

Comment: @DanceSC see the link that KRyan added in their comment (which I really should have added to my own.)  If you feel strongly, try to help the original asker reshape the question into something viable or take it up on Meta.  Either way, that link will help you understand the headwinds you're up against; either way, we're not litigating it here in comments.

Comment: @DanceSC It’s not that it’s a “bad” question, or that we don’t think it is a real issue that might actually come up in someone’s campaign, it’s just that _we can’t answer it_. Even citing the books, those contradict themselves on this subject constantly. It is just pure opinion.

Comment: To add my two cents, the alignment system in pathfinder is tied to mechanics, therefor in universe it is an objective system. I see good and evil as selfless vs selfish. Looking at pathfinder's definition of evil "Evil people and creatures have little to no compassion for others, and will kill whenever it suits their purpose. These evil acts can be done out of selfishness and greed, for sport, or at the behest of an evil master." this aligns quite well. As sport is also often selfish pleasure. If this villain is killing with his focus being HIS goal regardless of others, that is evil.

Answer (score 4):

Detect evil does not care about how someone views themself.

It is based solely on the actions within the setting that are defined as good and evil, and can thus change according to a number of factors, but mostly falls to the DM/GM.

Conflict resulting in death does not make the PC's evil, but their intentions do. PC's are free to set traps, ambush, and do so many other things, yet are not generally evil for doing so. Normally this is because the ones they are facing are "evil" by their actions or just by being what they are.

This entire good/evil system is complicated because it in part reflects the real world. Globally there are acts that are deemed evil, such as killing someone. However most countries also have understandable self defense ideas where killing someone who was trying to kill you wont have the same result.

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes?

Comment: Not sure why you would get a downvote, you made a very clear and understandable point. Alignment is not based off of self righteousness. As a rule of thumb you can find a deity to align your views with and use their alignment as a guide.

Comment: "Detect evil does not care about how someone views themself." Contradicts with "Conflict resulting in death does not make the PC's evil, but their intentions do." – intentions are all about how someone views himself, so you are contradicting yourself here. Also, killing someone outside of your tribe was not seen as inherently evil for most of the human history. In ancient Rome patriarch could kill any member of his family just because and it wasn't seen as evil either.

Comment: @Molot "Intention" has a couple of meanings, "the thing that you plan to do or achieve" or "a determination to act in a certain way" I think you're using the latter and likely Fering the former. It comes down to interpretation and opinion... and that makes it exceptionally hard to answer decisively one way or another.

Comment: Niekell is correct in how I was trying to illustrate the point, but it seems I was not as clear as I meant to be. Ill consider clearing that up

Comment: This is getting downvotes because **it is wrong**: _sometimes_ alignment seems to ignore what people think of themselves. But then other times, it does not. The books aren’t consistent; claiming they are is wrong. The only valid answer to a question like this is “we can’t answer this question.” Which is why we stopped accepting questions like this.